# Ivory not increasing with mints in Kittens Game

Tags: kittens-game

In Kittens game I am running my mints and getting +0.166 ivory per second, but when looking at the amount of ivory it can't increase at all. Is there something that is causing my ivory to drop even though it should be rising?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ivory](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=ivory&redirect=no), like Furs, is automatically used up over time to provide a Happiness boost to your kittens. If the amount of Ivory you generate per tick doesn't exceed the amount automatically used per tick, you'll be unable to stockpile any. Furthermore, the Mint will only actually generate Furs and Ivory if you have enough Catpower and Gold to spend running the Mints; if you have a net negative of either of those resources, the Mints will only generate Furs and Ivory on the ticks in which a full tick of those resources can be spent.

The left sidebar shows details about all your resources, including net generation rate. Hovering your mouse cursor over the generation rate will show details for everything that is producing or consuming that resource. However, this rate may not reflect the actual rates if you're expending more of a resource than you're making (e.g. the Ivory rate won't visibly change if you run out of Catpower or Gold, as long as you're still making *some* Catpower and Gold).

If you want to stockpile Ivory, you can increase your generation rate by having more Mints active, or reduce demand by building Tradeposts.

Comment: The problem i have is my income from mints says its higher then the loss for happiness and i should be gaining 0.033 per tick, but it still does not increase. I know this decrease is factored in as it shows it when my mints are off.

Comment: @blobman1st Are you generating more Catpower and Gold than the Mints consume? If you run out of either of those, you'll only generate Ivory on the ticks where you have enough of each to meet the demands for one tick of conversion.

Comment: Yeah i completely forgot that mints use up catpower. Thanks